# MethodHandle cannot be cracked when using LambdaMetafactory?

Tags: java, reflection, record, methodhandle, lambda-metafactory

I want to convert a Record's constructor to a Function<Object[], T> using lambdametafactory (T is a generic type), here are my codes:

```
public record R(
        String a,
        String b
) {
}

private static void testRecord() throws Throwable {
    MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
    MethodHandle constructor = lookup.findConstructor(R.class, MethodType.methodType(void.class, String.class, String.class));
    constructor = constructor.asSpreader(Object[].class, 2);
    R r = (R) constructor.invokeExact(new Object[]{"a", "b"});
    System.out.println(r.a());
    System.out.println(r.b());
    MethodType methodType = constructor.type();
    CallSite callSite = LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(lookup,
            "apply",
            MethodType.methodType(Function.class),
            methodType.erase(),
            constructor,
            methodType);
    Function<Object[], R> f = (Function<Object[], R>) callSite.getTarget().invokeExact();
    R apply = f.apply(new Object[]{"a", "b"});
    System.out.println(apply.a());
    System.out.println(apply.b());
}
```

When using `constructor.invokeExact()` method, the record could be instantiated successfully, but the `CallSite` couldn't be generated by `LambdaMetafactory.metafactory()` method because of following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.invoke.LambdaConversionException: MethodHandle(Object[])R is not direct or cannot be cracked
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.AbstractValidatingLambdaMetafactory.<init>(AbstractValidatingLambdaMetafactory.java:143)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.<init>(InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(LambdaMetafactory.java:336)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a trick to circumvent this restriction. Instead of creating a `Function` bound to the `constructor` handle, create a `Function` bound to the `invokeExact` method of the handle, to be invoked on the specific handle:

```java
private static void testRecord() throws Throwable {
    MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
    MethodHandle constructor = lookup.findConstructor(R.class,
        MethodType.methodType(void.class, String.class, String.class));
    constructor = constructor.asSpreader(Object[].class, 2);
    R r = (R)constructor.invokeExact(new Object[] { "a", "b" });
    System.out.println(r.a());
    System.out.println(r.b());
    MethodType methodType = constructor.type();
    CallSite callSite = LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(lookup,
        "apply",
        MethodType.methodType(Function.class, MethodHandle.class),
        methodType.erase(),
        MethodHandles.exactInvoker(methodType), // target MethodHandle.invokeExact
        methodType);
    Function<Object[], R> f = (Function<Object[], R>)
        callSite.getTarget().invokeExact(constructor); // bind to <constructor>
    R apply = f.apply(new Object[] { "a", "b" });
    System.out.println(apply.a());
    System.out.println(apply.b());
}
```

The crucial part is to specify `MethodHandles.exactInvoker(methodType)` which creates an unbound handle to the `invokeExact` method of a handle like ours, i.e. having the type `(MethodHandle,Object[])R`. Then, specify the actual handle as argument to the instantiation, to be captured by the `Function`.

Comment: Interesting idea! It achieves more or less the same as the approach using a lambda expression. Though, I suppose this option can be useful if you don't statically know the target interface type.

Comment: It’s closer to a method reference `constructor::invokeExact` which you can’t express in source code because the compiler insists on handling `Throwable`.

Comment: And [`javac`  has a bug](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8302782) and ignores that requirement for `MethodHandles::invoke`.

Comment: Thanks guys for your answers! I want to know if there is any reason why this bug still haven't been fixed? I noticed that it was created half a year ago.

Comment: @benrush you would be surprised how little resources the JDK development has, compared to the size of the JDK. There are a lot of open bugs with low priority.

Answer (score 4):

Direct method handles are those that directly refer to Java methods, however, your method handle does not, because you use an adapter:

```
constructor = constructor.asSpreader(Object[].class, 2);
```

As such, it can not be used in combination with `LambdaMetafactory`.

LMF is a runtime API that serves as the implementation for the lambda and method reference language features. It is not really meant to be used directly, so there are some sharp edges as you've found out.

---

For indirect method handles, your options are either [`MethodHandleProxies`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandleProxies.html):

```
MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
MethodHandle constructor = lookup.findConstructor(R.class, MethodType.methodType(void.class, String.class, String.class));
constructor = constructor.asSpreader(Object[].class, 2);
Function<Object[], R> f = (Function<Object[], R>) MethodHandleProxies.asInterfaceInstance(Function.class, constructor);
```

---

Using a lambda expression to wrap the method handle:

```
MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
MethodHandle constructor = lookup.findConstructor(R.class, MethodType.methodType(void.class, String.class, String.class));
constructor = constructor.asSpreader(Object[].class, 2);
Function<Object[], R> f = args -> {
    try {
        return (R) constructor.invokeExact(args);
    catch (Throwable t) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Should no happen", t);
    }
};
```

---

Or you could spin your own class that implements the interface and wraps the method handle using a bytecode library like ASM.